# R combine list allocation and filling list by name

Tags: r, list

I'm trying to allocate memory for lists where I later write results to. You can do so with i.e.

`mylist <- vector(mode = "list", length = 10)`

But I often work with named items in the list and for loops. The names are based on the current iteration, so there are not available beforehand.

If I do now

```r
years <- c("2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014")

results_list <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(years))

for (year in years) {
  current_name <- paste("The year", year)
  value <- as.numeric(year)
  results_list[[current_name]] <- value
}

> results_list
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
NULL

[[4]]
NULL

[[5]]
NULL

$`The year 2010`
[1] 2010

$`The year 2011`
[1] 2011

$`The year 2012`
[1] 2012

$`The year 2013`
[1] 2013

$`The year 2014`
[1] 2014
```

it is not placed in one of the allocated spots but new ones are amended to the list. I understand that this is not unexpected, but my questions is would it be possible to replace the preallocated slots by name? Please remember, I do not have the names of the items available before the loop.

One possibility would be maybe to run the loop first to just generate the names and set up the list structure and then fill the list based on a second loop matching the named items. Do you think that would save memory and speed for large lists?

If this is not (easily) possible, I will rewrite my code to address the slots by index, independent of the name, and modify it afterwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the answer is no for your case. If you preallocate resources to `mylist`, then you may have to set names to elements in `mylist` first and then assign values according to names, thus requiring two separate steps.

If you want to set name and assign value in one line, maybe you can try the code below

```
years <- c("2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014")

mylist <- list()
for (i in years) {
  mylist[paste("The year",i)] <- as.numeric(i)
}
```

such that

```
> mylist
$`The year 2010`
[1] 2010

$`The year 2011`
[1] 2011

$`The year 2012`
[1] 2012

$`The year 2013`
[1] 2013

$`The year 2014`
[1] 2014
```

Comment: so your suggestion would be to setup the list first with the required names and then fill in the values by name? I think that would be possible, but it would end up in two separate calls, the first one to create all the names and the second one to generate and fill in the values. So there is no way to fill an unnamed slot by name?

Comment: @crazysantaclaus if you want to do it just by one call, you can see if my added solution is what you want

Comment: Hm I think I have to adjust my question to make more clear, what I want. I generate the names on the fly, Therefore I would not be able to use them beforehand to allocate a list of the correct size with the correct names

Comment: @crazysantaclaus I think you should use `mylist <- list()` instead of `results_list <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(years))`, and then you can use `for` loop. Please see my updates

Comment: but this does not include any allocation or? my lists in the end may contain several 10000s of items up to the size of GBs, that is why I want to pre-allocate resources beforehand

Comment: @crazysantaclaus if you preallocate resources to `mylist`, then you may have to first set names and then assign values, which requires two separate steps

Comment: Okay, so the answer to the original question is no. Could you make that clear in your answer? Than I can accept it. Thank you very much for your effort!

Comment: @crazysantaclaus Okey, I updated my answer, please check it out